# Tkinter couldn't connect to display ":0"

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinter for a project, when running the code I get the message

```
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_ tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"

echo $DISPLAY returns :0
```

I've tried export DISPLAY=:0 and export DISPLAY=:0.0 but it doesn't work.

I want to display the GUI on the screen of the laptop Im on(the answers regarding ssh on the forum seem unrelated).

I'm using ubuntu on windows.
I have tried using both python3 and 2.7 but I get the same message.

Comment: If you are running under the WSL you'll need to install an X server.

Answer (score 9):

Note: [WSL now supports Linux GUI apps natively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps)

Previous answer in case you hit issues :

Using WSL on windows to develop tkinter applications you have two main options.

1. Develop the app with cross-platform development in mind, then run the application via MS-DOS.  Using GitHub will help you deal with [Line Endings](https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) This is the course I recommend (and I use), especially if you are using Python 3.4+ which includes [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)
2. *Not recommended* is to install an x-server on Windows, in which case [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) seems the easiest to get working.  Once installed run :

   sudo apt-get install x11-apps
   ... then export your display as you did before ...

   export DISPLAY=:0

Test the installation by running an app like xcalc from within WSL ...
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itnvg.jpg)

```
xcalc
```

Here is a sample of a tkinter app running under Xming on WSL after i commented out the icon code ... [tkinter app on xming] [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOsuU.jpg)

Running the app through MS-DOS is my recommendation, when I tested xming it didn't deal with ".ico" files.  It is likely issues like this might hinder more complex applications. However if you do choose this route [more info is available here](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

if your OS is linux

run this command :

```
sudo xhost
```

then you see this -> `SI:localuser:<pc name>`

then run this command :

```
sudo xhost -SI:localuser:<pc name>
```

Answer (score 0):

As provided by @borrible in comments, you will need to install an X server. See [this page](https://esc.sh/blog/install-gui-ubuntu-server/) for details.